# Spring-Boot Thymeleaf localization issue

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My application works fine when I run it through Intellij (spring-boot jar). However, localized messages are not resolved when I manually deploy the war file to stand-alone tomcat. I get ??key??en_US 
(key being the message key)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the structure of your deployed war? Where are the ressource-bundle files located?

Comment: They are located in root classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by defining my own message source bundle.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat(true);
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");

    return messageSource;
}
```